# Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used

Tags: captions, packages, subcaption, warnings

I have used the following packages in my IEEEtran document class, but I am getting the above warning:
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.

I cannot upload or build the PDF on the conference website without removing this warning.
Please help me remove it.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[style=ieee,natbib=true,maxbibnames=3,minbibnames = 3]{biblatex} 
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize} % for IEEE bibfont size

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `caption` pacage in the first place? IEEE  probably has rules as how captions are suppose to be formatted. So why are you changing that? BTW: you don't need to load `amsfonts` either as `amssymb` already does automatically.

Comment: I need it to keep to font under the tables small by using \captionsetup{font=small}. I usually have 3 or 4 lines of text under tables, so it looks bad if it is in regular font. Why would that cause the warning though?

Comment: That styling is not up to you. As mentioned IEEE has set up a layout and expects people to follow it. I have been on the receiving end of conference material where authors did not follow the guidelines we gave them. It is really annoying and wastes a lot of time cleaning it up. `caption` is probably warning that `IEEEtran` has changed the caption setup and thus those changes will not be carried over by `caption`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should probably not use `biblatex`. `IEEEtran` comes with its own selection of BibTeX styles that you can use for submission. The `biblatex-ieee` style is unofficial and it is unlikely that the IEEE can process your submission properly if you use `biblatex` (because it requires a workflow that is very different from the BIbTeX workflow that the template normally uses).

Answer (score 0):

One potential option is to silence the warning with the `silence` package.
To hide the warning put this snippet above the `\usepackage{caption}` line.

```latex
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{caption}{Unknown document class (or package)}
```

Comment: This does only hide the message, but the compatibility issue is still there. IMHO hiding warnings of classes or packages is not really a good idea.